# Where do I store shareable data in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building an app with various pages, and when users goes to `/orgs` I have a template that I require

```
// routes.js
...
import Orgs from './components/Orgs.vue';
...

{
  path: '/orgs',
  component: Orgs,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true }
},
```

from here I have a simple template in `Orgs.vue` that looks like:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div> {{orgs}} </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data(){
    return {
      orgs: [];
    }
   },
   created() {
     //use axios to fetch orgs 
      this.orgs = response.data.orgs;  

   }
}
</script>
```

The problem is that if I want to show list of organizations in other pages, I am bound to duplicate the same code for other pages as well, but I am trying to find a solution that would call return organizations so I can use that in multiple page?

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the list of organizations to persist in the same session, across various pages? Just store it in localStorage ;) and check it during the `mounted` lifecycle hook. If it is present, retrieve it and update the component's data. If it's not... run axios again.

Comment: Have a look at [VueX](http://vuex.vuejs.org). It implements a common store that can be accessed by all components, so you could store your orgs in there and also retrieve it from there in other components.

Comment: @Terry I thought about writing it in localstorage, but it is sensitive data, and sometime it can be a big content, storing the entire json response in localstorage/session does not seem the best choice

Comment: @cello That's is what I was thinking of before I wrote the question, but as a bigger in vuejs myself, the learning curve would be very steep, I'm wandering if there are other alternatives, like creating components that only export data (like fetch api) the including these files whenever I need it

Comment: VueX is useful, but not when navigating across different pages: the state/data will be reset, unless you are using a localStorage plugin for it: https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate. LocalStorage is secure because browsers restrict it based on domains: even subdomains of the same domain **cannot** access localStorage of each other. Typically there is a 5MB limit on localStorage, and I highly doubt a JSON blob will exceed that size... unless you are exporting a DB/table or the likes.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean accross different page? I am not using PHP or something like that, the pages that I have in my vue app are generated by the vue-router. So, the page does not actually refresh  (at least I don't see it refreshing) but for some reason, a value initialized in one page does not exist in another ... anyway, I will look at vuex + the localstorage option

Comment: You can import the same component on multiple pages. If you mean that you don't want to duplicate memory allocated to storing organizations, then use Vuex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make data available across the application use `Vuex`.
It is state management library which stores all the application data in a single source tree.

If you don't want to you `vuex` for the above issue, you can try `mixins`.
`Mixins` are best way to share functionality.

For the above case you can try a mixin like this.

`organisation.mixin.js`

```
const OrganisationMixin = Vue.mixin({
    data: function () {
        return { orgs: [] }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchOrgs: function() {
        // api to fetch orgs
          this.orgs = result_from_api
        }
    }
    mounted: function() {
        this.fetchOrgs()
    }
});
export default OrganisationMixin
```

Now let's use the `mixin` we just created.

In `whatever_name_component.vue`:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div> {{orgs}} </div>
</template>

<script>
import OrganisationMixin from 'path_to_organisation.mixin.js'
export default {
   mixins: [OrganisationMixin]
   data(){
    return { orgs: [] }
   },
   mounted() {
     console.log(this.orgs) //provided by mixin` and value is equal to api response from mixin.
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like the next best thing, can you add which file the first piece of code live inside the application and how the second file (component) is calling it? I see no import or export and I want to try it

Comment: Thanks. It works, just a error .. `fetchOrgs` should be inside a `methods: {}` function

Comment: happy to hear it worked, Yes it was an oversight, will edit.